# How can I generate LLVM code coverage in IR representation?

Tags: llvm, code-coverage

The tutorial (http://logan.tw/posts/2015/04/28/check-code-coverage-with-clang-and-lcov/) has an example to C code. I need evaluate the coverage on LLVM IR code.

How can I do this using clang or other tool?

Comment: @Ismail Badawi, I would like evalute the code coverage on this simple hello.ll (http://godev.ifrn.edu.br/valerio/hello.ll).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the same way -- the coverage instrumentation pass is implemented at the IR level, and clang can accept IR files (`.ll`) as input. Just make sure those files have debug info.

Comment: It is not working following this steps:
1)`clang -S -emit-llvm -c test.c`
2)`clang -o test -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage test.ll`
3)`./test`

It is not generating a gcno file or debug file.
What is wrong ? Could you give me a correct example?
Regards

Comment: @user1301985 Like I said, the files need to have debug info. Pass `-g` in step 1.

Comment: With your suggestion, I can evaluate the coverage on C code. I'm not interested in code coverage in C (It was only a example.)
I have a code generator from my language to llvm IR.
I would like to evaluate code coverage on the LLVM IR produced.